# Runescape 3: New account and Character Creation?

Tags: runescape

Is Runescape 3 will you be creating a new character or can you continue on with your Character from Runescape 2.

Comment: Runescape 3 has not been released yet, so this is unanswerable.  I am voting to close based on that.

Comment: Normally, I would agree, but it's not really a new game so much as an unreleased update that has been in beta for months, and Jagex has announced the answer to this question about 17 times. I mainly hesitate to close because of the beta status.

Comment: @murgatroid99 A cursory scan showed it was more like a new game than just an update.  If it is just an update, then I withdraw the objection.

Comment: Ahh ok, I understand know. I thought it would be a new game. Sucks it isn't. I need a fresh start after I forgot my account info and I can't get i back.

Comment: @fbueckert The switch to Runescape 3 is quite expansive, but it will still be the same underlying game. It's basically just an interface update, a client update, a graphical update, an audio update, and new content all released at once into the existing game.

Comment: @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec You know, if you need a fresh start you could just create another account. I'm pretty sure inactive accounts lose their names, so you could even get your name back eventually.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mind a fresh start as the last time I played it still had the old combat system. I don't like the recovery system that Ryunescape runs. Compared to like the Blizzard system. I never managed to recover my account with them. I mean I never remember my answer to a secrete I created in late 2008 :L

Comment: @murgatroid99 They were talking about a beta program, and I don't know of any major update to an MMO that doesn't do that through a test server, not a beta program.  That threw me off.

Comment: I don't know; I don't play other MMOs. But Runescape likes to do betas for major updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been confirmed that you keep your account information, characters, and items.
Runescape 3 isn't a new game, just a major update.